# TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null - react. jest enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Using react 16.3.1, jest 16.3.1, enzyme 3.3.0.

Within my React Class component I have created a react ref which I use to ensure that when the component is mounted the browser is at the top of the page.

```
class PageView extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.topOfPageRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.topOfPageRef.current).scrollIntoView();
  }

  render(){
    const { x } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="main-wrapper" ref={this.topOfPageRef}>
         Top
        </div>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

This all works perfectly within the browser but fails in my enzyme test.

My test is simple, it just tries to render the component.

```
  it('should render component correctly', () => {
    const props = {
      ...defaultProps,
    };
    const wrapper = mount(<PageView {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null`

I have tried both **shallow** and **mount** methods and whilst the element found is not null, it appears to be a react instance of HTMLDivElement which is missing the scrollIntoView method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Error message clarification**

Using `mount` like in the sample code above gives this error:

`TypeError: _reactDom2.default.findDOMNode(...).scrollIntoView is not a function`

Using `shallow` gives the error listed above:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null`

---

### shallow

**Issue**

`shallow` does not do DOM rendering so there will never be a DOM node on which to call `scrollIntoView()`.

**Solution**

Any code that does DOM manipulation needs to be tested using the full DOM rendering provided by `mount`.

---

### mount

["The default environment in Jest is a browser-like environment through jsdom"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string).

["`jsdom` is a pure-JavaScript implementation of many web standards...[that] emulate[s] enough of a subset of a web browser to be useful for testing"](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#--------jsdom).

**Issue**

`jsdom` implements much of the browser environment but it does not implement everything.  Of particular note for this question is that it does not implement `scrollIntoView` since `jsdom` [does not do layout and would therefore not be able to provide an accurate implementation](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1695#issuecomment-269528292).

Because `jsdom` does not implement `scrollIntoView` it will be undefined on elements provided by `jsdom`.

**Solution**

The [recommended approach from this Google dev](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/pull/2332#issuecomment-414073993) is to add the following line to your test code:

`Element.prototype.scrollIntoView = () => {};`

That line will add a noop implementation of `scrollIntoView` to the `jsdom`-provided `Element`.

For your test you could take it a step further and set `scrollIntoView` to a `spy` to make sure it is called:

```js
it('should render component correctly', () => {
  const props = {
    ...defaultProps,
  };
  Element.prototype.scrollIntoView = jest.fn();  // set scrollIntoView to a spy
  const wrapper = mount(<PageView {...props} />);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  expect(Element.prototype.scrollIntoView).toHaveBeenCalled();  // PASSES
});
```

---

Also, Antonio is correct that you shouldn't need to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()`, you should be able to use `this.topOfPageRef.current` directly:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.topOfPageRef.current.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: I see this fix everywhere, but were are you importing Element from?  I get 'Element is not defined' I am using enzyme with chai.

Comment: @JamesTrickey `Element` refers to the [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) class from the DOM.  The [default test environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) for `Jest` is a browser-like environment provided by `jsdom`, which provides the `Element` class in the global scope (like the browser does).

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. I am using enzyme but not jest, so that will be why the global is not there. In the end extracted the functionality to a 'service' that is passed to the component so it can be mocked. Not ideal but stopped the errors. Cheers guys!

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because ReactDOM.findDOMNode is giving you back null.

As the React doc says:

> When a component renders to null or false, findDOMNode returns null

also

> In most cases, you can attach a ref to the DOM node and avoid using findDOMNode at all.

You should not use React.findDOMNode

```
componentDidMount() {
   ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.topOfPageRef.current).scrollIntoView();
}
```

but:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.topOfPageRef.current.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set in window

```
  it('should call paginator component', () => {
      window.HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = jest.fn();
      // arrange
      // act
      // assertion
  })
```